# Mostrar colores de un array en JavaFx

Tags: java, array, javafx

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo este pequeño programa en JavaFx que me recorre la imagen y me muestra todos los colores que tiene, en la tabla de al lado muestro el codigo del color, pero quiero mostrar el color visible y no el codigo y quisera saber como podría rellenar cada celda del color correspondiente al código que tiene alli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí esta un código ejemplo, puedes modificar los datos de interes pero recuerda que es la misma estructura y se lo puedes aplicar a cualquier columna.

```
public void modificarCelda(TableColumn<Modelo_Mensual, String> cedulas){ // columna de interes
    cedulas.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Modelo_Mensual, String>, TableCell<Modelo_Mensual, String>>(){ // cambiar el factor o como se va a comportar la celda
        @Override
        public TableCell<Modelo_Mensual, String> call(TableColumn<Modelo_Mensual, String> param) {

            return new TableCell<Modelo_Mensual, String>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {//actualizando la celda con los parametros de interes
                    super.updateItem(item, empty); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

                  if (item != null){ //esta es para asegurarse que haya informacion
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color:#"+item); //y se coloca el estilo de fondo segun el color que mencione la celda
                        //-fx-background-color:#f0f8ff //este es un ejemplo de como debe quedar.
                 }

                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias, me salvaste la vida, me funciono perfecto.